# Use mnemonics/menu-shortcut keys with Windows apps running on Mac

Tags: keyboard, windows, shortcut, macos

I installed Crossover and then EditPlus. The app starts up great:  but the feature I was most interested in - mnemonics - is *not* working. They should be activated by hitting <kbd>option</kbd> + < Key> but instead European characters are placed in the editor panel.

[image]
Has anyone figured out how to do mnemonics for Windows Apps?   iirc the same thing happened with *linux* apps accessed via `XWindows`.

Comment: an alternative would be bbedit.  has a free and paid version.

Comment: @historystamp it's not about the editor - it's about the mnemonics.  I already have the best editor one can find on Mac - it's called pycharm/intellij. yes I use it as a general purpose editor. But that app is even better when mnemonics are fully working

Comment: It's an option you need to change it in preferences. see this thread: https://www.codeweavers.com/support/forums/general/?t=27;mhl=80205;msg=80190#msg80205

Comment: @historystamp  the implied availability by that thread notwithstanding there is no option in the preferences

Comment: Suggest you ask over in crossover support forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked in support from Crossover and the answer is:

Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd>

This *does* work. There is a separate problem then is that the movement keys using <kbd>Command</kbd> such as

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd>   for <kbd>End</kbd>

do not work. But I'll handle that separately.